# When should a singular word ending in "y" end in "ies" plurally?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, suffixes, silent-letters, irregular

Words like "sky" and "money" have "ies" as a plural suffix (i.e. "skies" and "monies") but other words like "monkey" and "Emmy" do not ("monkeys" and "Emmys"). Is there a rule dictating the use of "ies"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's determined by the letter before the y:

- Monk**ey**: vowel + y → monk**eys**
- s**ky**: consonant + y → s**kies**

Exception: proper nouns like "Emmy" sometimes form the plural by adding "s".

*Monies* I don't know about, so hopefully someone else can fill in that detail.

Comment: The question mentioned *money* → *monies*. Surely that is an exception too.

Comment: @Timwi: you are right, again. Since "money" is not a singular but an uncountable noun, I'm not clear on that.

Comment: The word can be "moneys" or "monies".  OED says: "In the plural, both moneys and monies are found in modern use; monies occurs especially in legal contexts."  Also, I see many older entries in the OED for "monie" as a singular, so the legal term may have been created then, and then stayed around because of that (as often happens with legal terms, see British "judgement": http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/judgment-or-judgement)

Comment: There's one in every crowd, has to break the rules. It's a bit weird if you ask me. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: According to [this](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=monies), "monies" came into usage in the mid-19th century, after "moneys", so it's probably only an exception to the rule as a result of an alteration of the form which fit the rule.

Answer (score 2):

*Monies* is one of those words where an error crept in and is now accepted as an exception. The plural of *money* (and there IS a plural in legal and accounting) should be, and is still acceptable as, *moneys*, and then there isn't an exception.

The general rule - if the Y is preceded by a consonant, then it is replaced by **ies**. If the Y is preceded by a vowel, add **s**.

This also works for verbs (I *carry* - he *carries*, I *play*, he *plays*). Nice and consistent.