# Use of apostrophes

Tags: apostrophe

Should it read "The contractor shall provide details of the companies ability with regard to resources" or "The contractor shall provide details of the companys ability with regard to resources"? Is there a need for an apostrophe here?

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2178/when-should-a-singular-word-ending-in-y-end-in-ies-plurally.

Comment: Also possible partial duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/is-s-ever-correct-for-pluralization .

Comment: It's not clear if the question is asking about the plural of _company_, or the possessive of _company_, or asking if it's better to write _companies'_ (possessive of _companies) or _company's_ (possessive of _company_).

Answer (score 9):

If there is one company, use *company's ability*. If there are many companies, use *companies' ability*.

Comment: *Companies' ability* is correct if there are many companies working as a whole; *companies' abilities* is better if there are many companies with each being considered as an independent unit.  (It does seem most likely from the source quote that there is only one company, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Correct:

> The contractor shall provide details of the company's ability with regard to resources.

The fact that the sentence contains *of* is irrelevant; *of* is merely a preposition that governs the noun phrase *[the company's ability with regard to resources]*. Strip away the modifying phrase *[with regard to resources]* and you're left with *[the company's ability]*.

In this case, it should be clear that this is a straightforward singular possessive, hence *company's* rather than any other alternative.