# "Destroyed" vs "Destroied"

Tags: past-tense

I recently observed that a non native speaker of english use the word "destroied" instead of "destroyed". It made me wonder why it is not "destroied". For "cry" it is "cried" but not "cryed". How it is determined or what rules decide what to use?

Comment: You might find this helpful if you're just looking for rules: [Changing Y to I with Suffixes](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Changing-Y-to-I-with-Suffixes.htm). If you're looking for something more than just the rules, you may want to edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: This is in effect a duplicate of [this question about nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2178/191178).

Comment: English spelling is a matter of tradition and doesn't follow rules. Each word has its own spelling, which almost looks like it makes sense, but never does.

Comment: @JohnLawler Spelling follows rules. It's just there are lots of different rules that often conflict.

Comment: @Acccumulation If they conflict, they're not correct rules. And since they don't predict spelling correctly, it's not very helpful to know them, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You cited *cried*.  Do you know any example where *-oy* becomes *-oied* instead of *-oyed*?  I don't.
How about *-ay* or *-ey* or *-uy* (if any)?

For *-oied* the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=*oied&_searchBtn=Search) (subscription required) has only two:  *ototoied*, past tense of the verb  *ototoi*; and *voied*, alternate spelling of *void*.

Comment: There are near misses in that "say" becomes "said" (and similarly "pay" -> "paid", "lay" -> "laid" - though "play" -> "played").