# Is the spelling 'judgment' a feature of American English? (As opposed to the other -dg[e]ment words?)

Tags: orthography, north-american-english, transatlantic-differences

According to the dictionary, the "e" is optional when a word ends in "-dg(e)ment".

Dictionary examples:

> - [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/acknowledgement):
>   "acknowledgement" (also "acknowledgment")
> - [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/judgement):
>   "judgement" (also "judgment", especially in North American English)
> - [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/abridgement):
>   "abridgement" (also "abridgment")

...And some other similar examples from the internet: ledg(e)ment, lodg(e)ment, grudg(e)ment.

Of these, only *judgment* is explicitly said to be found "especially in North American English"; regional distinctions don't seem to play a role in any of the other options.

Is this statement verifiable? What is the evidence, and how widespread is the variation? Is there a historical reason for *judgment* being unique in this sense? (If it even *is* unique...)

Comment: That is the way it goes: doughnut is donut, sulphur is sulfur, etc. I see there is a  Cambridge Dictionary entry for [acknowledgment](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acknowledgment) but as a BrE speaker I have never seen the 'e' omitted from the words you mention.

Comment: But I just checked my Mac's dictionary, and it shows "judgment" as the primary spelling.

Comment: Spelling is arbitrary and a matter of opinion.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's just, like, you know, you're opinyun, man.

Comment: _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) gives precedence to _abridgment_, _acknowledgment_, and _judgment_, with the silent-'e' forms offered as secondary alternative spellings. I was somewhat surprised to discover that MW also prefers _lodgment_ to _lodgement_. That's a level of consistency bordering on the eerie, when you consider that MW Online promotes such inexplicably divergent preferences as _decision-maker_ and _policymaker_, and _childcare_ and _health care_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the proper spelling “judgment” or “judgement”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/is-the-proper-spelling-judgment-or-judgement) Duplicate.

Comment: Cripes. This is not a question about opinion. It may very well be closable as  a duplicate, but please stop 'pressing the button'. Stop using 'opinion' as a close reason for questions that don't ask about opinion.

Comment: @Mitch - the first two close votes were from when the question was in the 'Do you agree?' state, which I think _was_ subjective.

Comment: @Heartspring OK I see, I didn't check the timeline. Maybe I was too strong. But still, if it is salvageable, wait until a salvage attempt is made before scuppering it further (you tried to salvage it so that's something).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the relevant graphs on Ngram (e.g. [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=judgement%2Cjudgment&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3)), it appears that:

- In all three cases (*judg(e)ment*, *acknowledg(e)ment*, and *abridg(e)ment*), the version without the "e" is more common in American English. This is particularly true in the case of *judgment*; the spelling *judgement* is very rare in American English.
- In the case of *acknowledgement*, and *abridgement,* the spelling with the "e" is more common in British English. In the case of *judgment,* though, the spelling without "e" is more common, though this preference isn't nearly as strong as it is in American English.

Trying a few more examples, it seems that, in general, in American English these words are more commonly spelled without the "e," whereas the "e" is usually included in British English. The major exception is in the case of "judgment," where American English strongly prefers, and British English allows, the spelling without the "e."